# How to handle Send Email Limit using Cron in Cpanel?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, html-email

I have developed a custom newsletter sending module using php in which admin can send newsletter to subscribers. Newsletter can be designed within the module and can be send by selecting the category of subscribers that contain thousands of emails with one click. Now issue is i have a restriction of sending 500 emails per hour. Using sleep() cause expiry of max execution script time.

After some research it came to me that this can be done via cron job. I created a cron job in cpanel that is set to every 5 minutes but i am not able to figure out that how this cron job will be triggered when admin click on send newsletter button in administrative panel. I am using swiftmailer library and querying subscriber table on some category id.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

Have two tables. One for the email being sent and one for the emails that the newsletter is going to with what newsletter the email is receiving.

**Structure examples**

table `newsletter` :

- `id` - Auto INC
- `email_subject` - Subject of newsletter
- `email_html` - HTML version of the email
- `email_plain_text` - Plain text version of email
- `created_datetime` - datetime newsletter was created

table `newsletter_recipients`:

- `id` - Auto INC
- `newsletter_id` - ID of what newsletter is being sent out (create a foreign key referring to the `id` field on the `newsletter` table
- `email` - HTML version of the email
- `name` - Name of client
- `sent` - Whether the email was sent off or not (this isn't required, see below)

When the administrator sends the email create the newsletter row with the html/plain text version (you can use only one column, just better to have a html and plain text version of email) and also add the recipients to the newsletter_recipients table referring the newsletter_id to the id of the newsletter you added.

Now you have your PHP cron job file run every hour. This file will check if any clients need a newsletter sent out and if so send it out. Once sent out you can either delete the recipient row or mark it as sent. Personally I would delete them to keep data from backing up. Only run the php job up till 500 or whatever amount of emails you want to send out then have the script end. Next hour it will run and pick up the next 500.

With this system the newsletter wont be sent out immediately, it will be done when the cron job runs. But this is the best solution I can quickly think up for you. That or get a mail server that lets you send out all the emails you want and use something like gearman to handle load balancing.

NOTE: Storing the newsletter in a database can be handy so the admin can look back and see when they sent out their newsletter. Also you can step it up another level and create a `sent_date` column on the `newsletter_recipient` table that stores when the email was sent (if you are simply marking the recipient as sent or not instead of deleting) that way you know when the emails finished sending, who received the emails at what time, etc. This is totally up to you).